# Посчитать скидку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой код HTML

```js
$('#saleForm input').on('change', function() {
 let inputVal = $('input[name=radio-sale]:checked').val();
 let prices =   $('.priceJs');
    $.each(prices,function(index,value){
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="priceJs">95</span>
<span class="priceJs">85</span>
<form id="saleForm">
  <div class="sale">
      <label>
          <input  class="sale-btn" type="radio" name="radio-sale" value="15" >
      При покупке продукции от 750 гривен скида 15%
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="sale">
      <label>
          <input class="sale-btn" type="radio" name="radio-sale" value="35">
      При покупке продукции от 10000 гривен скида 35%
      </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

В работе будет много `<span class="priceJs">--</span>`
Я получаю при клике на `input` нужное значение `value` 15 или 35.
И получаю список элементов с классом `priceJs`.
Вопрос такой, как мне взять значение каждого элемента  `priceJs` и вывести туда новые значения с учетом скидки? 
Когда пытаюсь взять значения `value.text()` получаю ошибку:

> scripts.min.js:75 Uncaught TypeError: value.text is not a function

Comment: уберите скобки и возьмите просто значение `value.text`

Comment: Теперь  undefined

Comment: console.log($(value).text());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял.

```js
$('.sale-btn').on('change', function() {
  let val = this.value;
  let prices = $('.priceJs'), new_price = 0;
  
  $.each(prices,function(index,value){
    new_price = (+$(value).attr('data-d') * val)/100;
    $(value).text(new_price);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="priceJs" data-d="95">95</span>
<span class="priceJs" data-d="85">85</span>
<form id="saleForm">
  <div class="sale">
      <label>
          <input  class="sale-btn" type="radio" name="radio-sale" value="15" data-span="1">
      При покупке продукции от 750 гривен скида 15%
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="sale">
      <label>
          <input class="sale-btn" type="radio" name="radio-sale" value="35" data-span="2">
      При покупке продукции от 10000 гривен скида 35%
      </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Посчитать нужно для каждого блока  priceJs  Цену со скидкой 15% или 35%

Comment: @Дмитрий Подправил

Comment: Да я сейчас тоже дошел до такого результата. Но теперь нажимаю несколько раз на проценты получается что они буду считать от текущего значения

Comment: @Дмитрий ну так поставьте `disabled` после клика.  Или делайте буфер)

Comment: как его сделать то )

Comment: @Дмитрий, это уже другой вопрос) Если я ответил на данный вопрос, примите его. Так же посмотрел другие ваши вопросы, тоже примите их если вас устраивают ответы.

Comment: Ответ подходит. Если не сложно помогите еще  и  с вопросом о том как сделать так чтобы считало от первоначального значения

Comment: Я вроде как логику понимаю но как написать это на JQ незнаю...Надо создать масси из первоначальных значений цены и каждый раз считать от него проценты.

Comment: @Дмитрий подправил.

Comment: Понял как вы решили проблему! Добавили data-d="95" атрибут.  Спасибо огромное. Поправили мне немного мозги. Я уже  наворотил там такого что просто жесть....